# Laravel server to client communication

Tags: laravel, sockets, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, supervisord

I need to implement a server to client communication. Long polling sounds like a non-optimal solution. Sockets would be great. I'm looking at this package:

https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets

My server is running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (with a second worker environment for queue and cron).

Does anyone have experience setting up a socket connection in Elastic Beanstalk? In particular, how can I start up a socket server using ebextensions (or any way at all). Looks like I should be using supervisor for the server.

Should this server live in the worker environment? Can it? I don't know much about the moving parts here. Anything is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel comes with out of the box broadcasting tool : Laravel Echo.
And you can either use it with a local instance (by deploying Redis for example), or you can use an API or an external tool (Socket.IO, Pusher ..)
Take a look at the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting